# Multiprocessing Object Method with Pathos Has no Speed Up

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, dill, pathos

I want to call the `buildWorld` method of each of several `world` objects. This is a computationally expensive and time-consuming task, sometimes taking several hours depending on the settings you give each `world`.

After initially running into the issue that pickle couldn't serialize my object methods (described [here](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2013/12/05/Parallelism-and-Serialization) and in several questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422581/python-multiprocessing-basic-cant-pickle-local-object-and-ran-out-of-input) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72766345/attributeerror-cant-pickle-local-object-in-multiprocessing)), I tried using pathos. The multiprocessing did not improve performance, so I did a time check on just pure serialization of my objects to see if this was the source of the slowdown, but it wasn't. Nevertheless, I eventually took an approach where I created a `world` **within** the child process rather than pass it in, then saved it as a file that I could re-load in my parent process to avoid having to serialize anything on a `return` (and also on child process start, I assume?). I came across several similar questions ([A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727375/multiprocessing-pool-slower-than-just-using-ordinary-functions) & [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382319/python-multiprocessing-pathos-slow)), and tried a few things (see below), but none of the answers seemed to do the trick for me.

Unfortunately, nothing actually sped up my code. I was seeing that child processes were being created, but if I created 3 subprocesses, for example, my code ran 3x slower, and so took just as much time as if I ran just one process. Any guidance is appreciated!

**Method 1 (Pathos ProcessingPool):**

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp

def run_world_building(worldNum):
  myWorld = emptyWorld(worldNum) # not expensive
  myWorld.buildWorld()           # very expensive
  myWorld.save()                 # create a file with world info

p = mp.ProcessingPool(3)
p.map(run_world_building, range(0,3))
```

**Method 2 (Multiprocess (no '-ing') with individual Process objects):**

```
import multiprocess as mp

def run_world_building(worldNum):
  myWorld = emptyWorld(worldNum) # not expensive
  myWorld.buildWorld()           # very expensive
  myWorld.save()                 # create a file with world info

processes = []
for i in range(0,3):
  p = mp.Process(target=run_world_building, args=(i,))
  processes.append(p)

# I separated the start and join loops, but
# not sure if that's entirely necessary
for i in range(0, 3):
  processes[i].start()
for i in range(0,3):
  processes[i].join()
```

**Method 3 (Using ThreadPool):**

```
from pathos.pools import ThreadPool

def run_world_building(worldNum):
  myWorld = emptyWorld(worldNum) # not expensive
  myWorld.buildWorld()           # very expensive
  myWorld.save()                 # create a file with world info

p = ThreadPool(3)
p.map(run_world_building, range(0,3))
```

Comment: What is the cpu utilization without and with multiprocessing ? chances are you were already at 100%, it could also be a memory bottleneck, but that one is slightly harder to pin down.

Comment: It would also be nice to know what kind of workloads are we talking about, vector math ? Or creation of python objects ? Or linear algebra? Or image processing? Or loading data from disk ? Or gpu work ? Expensive is sort of broad.